# perl array processing at once

Tags: arrays, perl, hash, hashmap

I have an array with many many entries like:

```
"a->b->c->x->n"
"something->something1->somethingelse"
```

I want to extract all odd elements from the array at once and make a hash with their unique values, like:

```
%s = {
  "b" => '1'  
  #the values don't matter too much, they could be # occurences, I am going to use keys %s.
  "x" => '1'
  "something1" => '1'
}
```

Currently I am doing this in a couple steps but just looping through the array is taking a substantial amount of time so I think there is someway to do it better.

```
my ( @odds, @evens );
foreach (@arr) {
  my $i = 0;
  push @{ $i++ % 2 ? \@odds : \@evens }, $_ for split /->/, $_;
}
%s = map {  $_ => '1'; } @odds;
```

Any suggestions to process the whole array at once?

Comment: @ikegami: I have seen perl code where an entire array is processed at once, for example with grep or map.  I thought this could be faster than looping through each entry.

Comment: You are mistaken. `grep` and `map` are just as much loops as `for`, and the assignment that assigns the resulting scalars to the array equally loops over all the scalars.

Comment: Notes.  1) Use `for my $i (0..$#arr)`  2) Collect only odds /// Otherwise, you must visit each element, and you must visit each (second) substring. (But trying to visit _only each second_ substring needs function calls and it will only be slower.)

Comment: Re "*`grep` and `map` are just as much loops as `for`*", Actually, `for(@a) BLOCK` is more efficient than `map BLOCK @a` and `grep BLOCK @a` because it's optimized to iterate over the indexes of `@a` while `map` and `grep` put all the elements of `@a` on the stack.

Answer (score 3):

Your request makes no sense. If you want to perform something to each element of the array, you will necessarily have to loop through every element of the array (whether `for` is used or not).

And I don't see anything in that code that would be slow (unless the OS started using virtual memory because you are running out of memory). It is wasteful to populate `@evens` and never use it.

The following is a cleaner version of your code. It's also faster (thanks to `pairvalues` and avoiding temporary storage), but it shouldn't be substantially so.

```
use List::Util qw( pairvalues );  # 1.29+

my %s;
for (@arr) {
   ++$s{$_} for pairvalues split /->/;
}
```

If you don't mind weird/ugly code, the following is even faster (if only marginally):

```
use List::Util qw( pairvalues );  # 1.29+

my %s;
for (@arr) {
   undef @s{ pairvalues split /->/ };
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you're interested in only those elements of the lists that have an odd index then a C-style `for` loop is the obvious choice

```
use strict;
use warnings 'all';

my @arr = ( "a->b->c->x->n", "something->something1->somethingelse" );

my %s;

for ( @arr ) {

    my @k = split /->/;

    for ( my $i = 1; $i < @k; $i += 2 ) {
        $s{ $k[$i] } = 1;
    }
}

use Data::Dumper;
print Dumper \%s;
```

#### output

```
$VAR1 = {
          'b' => 1,
          'x' => 1,
          'something1' => 1
        };
```

You may also want to consider a regex solution if the values between the `->` are really as well-behaved as you describe. This assumes that the lists always contain an odd number of characters.

```
for ( @arr ) {
    $s{ $1 } = 1 while /->(\w+)->/g;
}
```

The result of this loop is identical to that of the previous code